# nextTick uses in vuejs and component update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm new to vue.js and I have an idea about its basics. Today I came across a sample code using nextTick() and had to read the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick) to understand what is good for but that complicated things and I still don't understand.

> A utility for waiting for the next DOM update flush.

- how the **next DOM update** is done ? is it automatic (timeout) or occurs on a specific action from the user?

> When you mutate the reactive state in Vue, the resulting DOM updates are not applied synchronously. Instead, Vue buffers them until the "next tick" to ensure that each component updates only once no matter how many state changes you have made.

- what is meant by **componenent is updated only once** ? and when this only once update is launched?
- what is the case I need to use nextTick?

Answer (score 0):

- what is meant by componenent is updated only once ? and when this only once update is launched ?

Lets say you have 3 variables:

```
 let age
 let home
 let name
```

And you change all of them at once. It would be very inefficient if you need to do 3 updates at once Instead of updating the DOM 3x it will save the state until the next tick occure and update it only 1x.

- what are the case i need to use nextTick ?

```js
Vue.component('popup', {
  template: `<div style="border: 1px solid gray" ref="popup" tabindex="0" @blur="close">
  <p>popuup</p>
</div>`,
  methods: {
     close() {
        this.$emit("close")
     },
  },
  created(){
     this.$refs.popup.focus()
  }
})


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    open: false
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
<button @click="open = true">open</button>

<popup @close="open = false" v-if="open"></popup>
</div>
```

Here an example: Here i have an popup item. Now i want whenever i click outside the box, to close it. For this i need to focus it on creation time so the blur even gets triggered when i click outside. The problem here is that the DOM element is not created yet. It will throw an error

The solution is to use `$nextTick()` so it actually waits until the DOM gets mounted and then this code will actually work.

```js
Vue.component('popup', {
  template: `<div style="border: 1px solid gray" ref="popup" tabindex="0" @blur="close">
  <p>popuup</p>
</div>`,
  methods: {
     close() {
        this.$emit("close")
     },
  },
  created(){
     this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.popup.focus()
     })
  }
})


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    open: false
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
<button @click="open = true">open</button>

<popup @close="open = false" v-if="open"></popup>
</div>
```

Comment: for the first part, I understand that make an update x3 is not efficient, but can you clarify what do you mean by "save the state until the next tick occure and update it only 1x" i.e after saving the state which action would make  the update at once occur ?

Comment: for the second part, so nextTick() is **only used with methods called in created() where the DOM is not yet mounted** ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, good questions. An update cycle in Vue goes like this:

- a change in data is detected (this ultimately triggers the next DOM update)
- all affected data is updated (watchers are executed, computed properties are updated, binds are reevaluated and so on)
- the DOM is updated to show the changes (since all changes are handled together, only one update is needed)
- wait for the next change

`nextTick()` is used to perform an action after the current cycle has concluded and DOM changes have been applied.

A typical case for `nextTick()` is when you enable an element by changing a condition in a `v-if` and want to scroll to it. If you run `scrollTo()` the moment you change the condition, the element will not be there (or at least not be fully rendered, causing the scroll to miss its actual position). But if you do it in `nextTick()`, it works.

Comment: you've said that **any change in data ultimately triggers the next DOM update** (this makes understand that every change is done separately), then how can we say that **all changes are handled together** ? can you give an example ?

Comment: @natalyren Oh, it's not just any data, but data that is wired into Vue (what Vue calls "reactive data"). If you have an `<input>` element that is not bound to Vue, writing into it will not cause any updates. But if Vue binds the value to a variable (i.e. through `v-model`), changing the content of the `<input>` might trigger validation, which then leads to a message if the input is not valid and disables the submit button. All of those changes would be calculated and handled together in the same update cycle.

Comment: does a click on a button (to dispay a popup or a drawer for example) trigger the dom update ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you wouldn't see a popup. Vue has really nice articles about what [rendering](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/rendering-mechanism.html) and [reactivity](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html) means on a technical level and how it works. Note however that you don't have to go that much into detail to use Vue successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below Vue component:

- How many times will Vue update your actual DOM (the `h1` element) when you click the *Update* button?
- We all know that eventually the `h1` element will display 2, but will it display 1 first before it displays 2?
- You might argue that you can still change DOM many times before it actually re-renders, which is true, so let's put it in this way: will the `h1` element ever be in such a state where its innerHTML == "1"?

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const counter = ref(0)

const update = () => {
  counter.value = counter + 1
  counter.value = counter + 1
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ counter }}</h1>
  <button @click="update">Update</button>
</template>
```

If you are not sure, write the component in this way and see the result yourself:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const header = ref();
const counter = ref(0)

const update = () => {
  counter.value = Number(header.value.innerHTML) + 1
  counter.value = Number(header.value.innerHTML) + 1
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1 ref="header">{{ counter }}</h1>
  <button @click="update">Update</button>
</template>
```

[see it in action](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqdUbtSwzAQ/JUbNYmHRMKtsT3QUQBV6NTYjoxtrMfoEZjx+N85RcT0dPfYW+2uFvJkDL0EQQpSus6OxoMTPpiaq1EabT0sYEV/UOLbn8buE1borZaww5sdV1x1WjkPg2jOwkIVsfvs4TbudFB+m99nfwfBnBsvcLHPoKph4QpuaHpp5hBXb0G2wu4Td5rSUSlhn0+vLxncQf7fq5WrkiW7aBQbL6SZURB2AOWQR70VJ4mEk3pZNi/rWrIhT8A2eK8VPHYzRoP45Arx79eiZAmA4JJtT5ADSdEeZWPo5LTC8K8B8N+F46RIkcQZJh17VOO9cQVjru/il02OavvBsKIWpY1SUOHksbX6y6HzCVkiBXpdyfoD7AOo3A==)

This is a very simple example to demonstrate what it means when Vue says it "**buffers changes**" so that components only get "**updated once**" no matter how many "**state changes**" you have made.

Obviously in this example you don't have to do two consecutive increments, but in reality, it is much harder to layout complicated state changes in strictly non-overlapping fashion. On the one hand, not all state mutations happen at a single location in your source code; and on the other hand, simple state changes easily trigger further state changes:

- computed properties will update
- watches will fire
- they all can trigger further computed properties and watches

State to template binding isn't trivial neither. It all comes down to the fact that Vue is dealing with reactive programming: your template is **declarative**, but Vue has to update your template **imperatively**.

Synchronously modifying the real DOM as you make changes to every individual reactive state field is not only expensive, but also wasteful sometimes.

Vue only applies state changes synchronously to the virtual dom, and Vue sync the virtual dom with your real dom when **you are done modifying the states**. In this case it is roughly when you exit the `update` method.

Internally Vue uses microtask queue to schedule the dom patching. The moment you make the first state mutation, Vue will schedule a flush job onto the microtask queue, through `Promise`. Micro task will not be executed until there is nothing else running, in other words, until the current **js call stack is empty**.

`nextTick` is such a method that directly dispatches a micro task to the micro queue, so that your callback will be called after all the other micro tasks (usually the Vue dispatches DOM operations). In fact, in nodejs the method to dispatch micro task is called exactly `nextTick` (google nodejs nextTick please).

So when do you want to use `nextTick`? Well, the key thing to remember is that **DOM is not changed synchronously while you are changing states**, so if you want access the DOM resulted from your state change, you have to use `nextTick`. Basically deferring yourself to the end of the queue so that Vue can patch the DOM first. Common use cases include e.g. focus an element that is conditionally rendered by your state change (to focus the element you need to have a template ref, but the template ref won't have value until Vue patches the DOM).